# Difficulty using SET within Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, social-engineering

When setting a website attack vector, I find that Kali does not give me the option to specify a port in order to receive information back to my local. Furthermore, I am unable to access the listener I created as I simply get a "this page cannot be loaded" error when I attempt to open the external IP address in another computer. My SET configuration is as follows:

```
set:webattack>3

The first method will allow SET to import a list of pre-defined web
 applications that it can utilize within the attack.

 The second method will completely clone a website of your choosing
 and allow you to utilize the attack vectors within the completely
 same web application you were attempting to clone.

 The third method allows you to import your own website, note that you
 should only have an index.html when using the import website
 functionality.

   1) Web Templates
   2) Site Cloner
   3) Custom Import

  99) Return to Webattack Menu

set:webattack>1
[-] Credential harvester will allow you to utilize the clone capabilities     within SET
[-] to harvest credentials or parameters from a website as well as place them into a report
[-] This option is used for what IP the server will POST to.
[-] If you're using an external IP, use your external IP for this
set:webattack> IP address for the POST back in     Harvester/Tabnabbing:73.196.210.4

  1. Java Required
  2. Google
  3. Facebook
  4. Twitter
  5. Yahoo

set:webattack> Select a template:2

[*] Cloning the website: http://www.google.com
[*] This could take a little bit...

The best way to use this attack is if username and password form
fields are available. Regardless, this captures all POSTs on a website.
[*] Apache is set to ON - everything will be placed in your web root directory of apache.
[*] Files will be written out to the root directory of apache.
[*] ALL files are within your Apache directory since you specified it to ON.
Apache webserver is set to ON. Copying over PHP file to the website.
Please note that all output from the harvester will be found under     apache_dir/harvester_date.txt
Feel free to customize post.php in the /var/www/html directory
[*] All files have been copied to /var/www/html
[*] SET is now listening for incoming credentials. You can control-c out of this and completely exit SET at anytime and still keep the attack going.
[*] All files are located under the Apache web root directory: /var/www/html
[*] All fields captures will be displayed below.
[Credential Harvester is now listening below...]
```

As you can see, I do not get the "Credential Harvester is running on Port 80" messages, and I am unable to use the harvester that I jsut created. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your apache2 service is running

```
service apache2 start
```

Note that using SET on a virtual machine might cause problems sometimes.

And finally, i guess in the newer versions of SET you wont find the username and password on the terminal itself, instead you will find them in the www directory

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is not a virtual machine. I will try your suggestion though